# Physically view the files in the original format that was uploaded to SP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, remote-blob-storage

We are using sharepoint 2013 .
we have installed and configured RBS with FILESTREAM in a SharePoint 2013 farm using [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631(v=office.15).aspx).

our files are stored in the specific folder in a computer .How to obtain the original files that are actually uploaded to SP from the blob storage folder.we can manually compare the sizes of the file uploaded and that of present in the folder .

How to view the files in the original format that was uploaded in the blob folder ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly view the externalized BLOBs in the filesystem. If you have a small setup, you can try to upload a text-file and match the files on the basis of filesize and creation date. If you open the externalized file you will see that it is no longer your original text-file you uploaded to SharePoint.

You should also consider that one file in SharePoint may be split across several files if you upload new versions. This is because of the new ShreddedStorage feature in SharePoint 2013 (good explanation here, chapter "What happens when you enable RBS?": http://www.avepoint.com/community/team-blog/the-truth-behind-shredded-storage/)

Comment: Is there any other method to physically obtain the uploaded file to SP?